# Want to fetch the MAX ROW in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, window-functions

I have SQL query :

```
select * from (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () MAX_ROW, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
UNIT_ID asc) RN, EQ.* from COAT.TBL_EQUIPMENT EQ) where RN between 1 and 10
```

But i have to implement the same in MySQL.
Can someone help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by `MAX ROW`?

Comment: Add some sample data and the expected result, if you want the question reopened.

Comment: 1) Ensure that you have MySQL version 8+, 2) Add alias to subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter: if you are running MySQL 8.0, this query should just work as it is (provided that you alias the subquery, as commented by Akina).

Now assuming that you are running an earlier version, one option is to `cross join` an aggregate query for the total count of rows, and to increment a user variable to emulate `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select e.*, m.max_row, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
    from (select * from tbl_equipment order by unit_id) e
    cross join (select count(*) max_row from tbl_equipment) m
    cross join (select @rn := 0) x
) t
where rn <= 10
```

Actually you might not even need the subquery:

```
select e.*, m.max_row, @rn := @rn + 1 rn
from (select * from tbl_equipment order by unit_id) e
cross join (select count(*) max_row from tbl_equipment) m
cross join (select @rn := 0) x
order by e.unit_id 
limit 10
```